# Using a dash (-) in ASP.MVC parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitUserName")) { %>
    <input type='text' name='user-name' />
    <input type='submit' value='Send' />
<% } %>
```

What should be a signature of a corresponding Action method to accept `user-name` parameter?

```
public ActionResult SubmitUserName(string user-name) {...}
```

Method signature above does not work for some reason ;-)

I know there is an `ActionNameAttribute` to handle situation with a dash in action name. Is there something like `ParameterNameAttribute`?

Comment: Do you really need to use dash?

Comment: is it **required** to be `user-name`?

Comment: It is not required at all. It just puzzling that MVC didn't think of this scenario. I don't actually use it, just curious if its there...or why it isn't there.

Comment: There are scenarios where you're using a third-party tool and you need to support dashes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As everyone has noted, the easiest fix would be not to use a dash. If you truly need the dash, you can create your own ActionFilterAttribute to handle it, though.

Something like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ParameterNameAttribute :  ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string ViewParameterName { get; set; }
    public string ActionParameterName { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(ViewParameterName))
        {
            var parameterValue = filterContext.ActionParameters[ViewParameterName];
            filterContext.ActionParameters.Add(ActionParameterName, parameterValue);   
        }
    }
}
```

You would then apply the filter to the appropriate Action method:

```
[ParameterName( ViewParameterName = "user-data", ActionParameterName = "userData")]
[ParameterName( ViewParameterName = "my-data", ActionParameterName = "myData" )]
    public ActionResult About(string userData, string myData)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

You would probably want to enhance the ParameterNameAttribute to handle upper/lower case, but that would be the basic idea.

Comment: `OnActionExecuting` should use `TryGetValue` to avoid the double lookup of `ContainsKey` followed by the indexer.

Answer (score 13):

Create a pseudo-parameter in the first line of the action method:

```
public ActionResult SubmitUserName()
{
    string userName = Request.Params["user-name"];
    ...
}
```

Comment: That didn't even compile for me. Are you talking about ApiController?

Comment: Oh silly me, the question is about MVC... and I'm doing Web API. OK then.

Answer (score 8):

Not answering the actual question based on the technlogy in question, but anyway, the world moves forward in some areas; in AspNetCore.Mvc you can simply do:

```
    [HttpGet()]
    public ActionResult SubmitUserName( [FromHeader(Name = "user-Name")] string userName) {...}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this answer helpful, but I don't know exactly how the provided example helps.  It appears to just "rename" a value that the binder all ready provided.

In my case, I was being posted to by an external service that would post something like "body-plain" and I could not control the name.  So I modified this sample to look like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ParameterNameMapAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string InboundParameterName { get; set; }
    public string ActionParameterName { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        object value = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request[InboundParameterName];

        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(ActionParameterName))
        {
            filterContext.ActionParameters[ActionParameterName] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Parameter not found on controller: " + ActionParameterName);
        }
    }
}
```

This actually takes in the parameter "body-plain" for example and maps it to an ActionParameter I defined on my controller. Like so:

```
[ParameterNameMap(InboundParameterName = "body-plain", ActionParameterName = "bodyPlainText")]
    [ParameterNameMap(InboundParameterName = "Thread-Topic", ActionParameterName = "alternateSubject")]
    public HttpStatusCodeResult Process(string token, string timestamp, string signature, string subject, string sender, string recipient, string bodyPlainText, string alternateSubject)
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing something like this - unless it's required to use the `user-name` attribute (or you're not binding to a model)

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitUserName")) { %>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName) %>
    <input type='submit' value='Send' />
<% } %>
```