# Web api map request parameter with a hyphen to a Pascal cased complex model property

Tags: asp.net-web-api, mailgun

I am trying to figure out a way to map POSTED form parameters that have hyphens in them to a WEB-API method that takes a complex object.

Some context:

We are using Mailgun to forward a processed email to our own custom Web API Controller method.

Mailgun POSTS to our API and some of the parameters it uses have hyphens in them - for example:  body-plain.

My C# complex model will have a property to match in Pascal Case (can't use hyphens in property names)

so if these parameters are generated by Mailgun and posted to our WEB API controller:

```
   from
   subject
   body-plain
   body-stripped
   timestamp
```

and our complex object looks like this:

```
public class Response{
   public string From{get; set;}
   public string Subject{get; set;}
   public string BodyPlain{get; set;}    
   public string BodyStripped{get; set;
   public int Timestamp{get; set;}
}
```

Then From, Subject, and Timestamp all map correctly - but BodyPlain and BodyStripped do not - they are null since the model binding can't translate the hyphenated parameters to Camelcase.

Is there a way to do this?

I have seen some posts referring to different ways to achieve this with MVC but we are not using MVC, just strictly WEB API.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Request` object in the controller, which will make the parameters available key/value style.

In the case of Mailgun forwarding (which was the same problem I ran into), the `Request.ReadFormAsync()` method will expose the `IFormCollection`, from which you can access the parameters you need via:

```cs
IFormCollection.TryGetValue("my-parameter", out StringValues myParameter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the parameters are sent through form submission and not JSON, using `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "my-param")]` won't help and you'll have to resort to having your action receiving a parameter of type `FormDataCollection` and then inside your action you'll map it to your complex object. An alternative is to implement a custom model binder.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32342016/1057791) there are details about those two options.